# Ubuntu crashes randomly

Tags: xubuntu, freeze, crash

I have a separate computer that I used to use for ethereum mining but now I have installed ubuntu onto it and it happens on just random occasion that the whole computer freezes and doesn't accept any input from either mouse or keyboard, the only thing I can do is restart the computer. I did also have this problem when I was using the computer as a miner running Xubuntu but now that I actually want to use the machine this is a problem I don't know how to solve, is there any way for me to log what happens right before a crash or is there some other way to find out what is happening and fix it.

the computer specifications

running Ubunut 20.04LTS

Motherboard: GIGABYTE F2A88XM-DS2

CPU: AMD A10-7890K-Radeon R7

GPU: Nvidia GTX 1070ti from MSI

HDD: a 1 terabyte WD hard drive

Comment: Welcome, please indicate in the question, [edit] it, what version of (X)ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`, `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -xe` to see the end of the previous boot's logs. Consider CPU overheating if the logs don't help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems it could be.

-Hard drive failing, check SMART data in `gnome-disks`

-CPU problem. As highlighted, could be overheating or worse

-Could actually be a RAM problem - try with 1 stick if you have more than 1 (and if you have other RAM, try use that to rule it out

-OS problem in itself (maybe some logs, dumps or just a corrupted sector)

Need more information though